# Laptop onboard camera doesn't work and flooded dmesg

Tags: usb, laptop, 20.04, webcam

I have an issue with my internal camera, it doesn't work anymore. I used it a few times without any issue before, but recently it stopped working. I disabled `uvcvideo` as it prevented some apps using camera to work (even without using the video). My `dmesg` output is flooded with these messages :

`[15790.697055] usb 1-13: Product: HD Webcam
[15790.697056] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[15790.697056] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[15790.700414] usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 39
[15791.080408] usb 1-13: new high-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[15791.180878] usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b68b, bcdDevice= 0.07
[15791.180879] usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15791.180880] usb 1-13: Product: HD Webcam
[15791.180880] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[15791.180881] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[15791.184280] usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 40
[15791.564440] usb 1-13: new high-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[15791.664853] usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b68b, bcdDevice= 0.07
[15791.664855] usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15791.664855] usb 1-13: Product: HD Webcam
[15791.664856] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[15791.664857] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[15791.668066] usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 41`

It looks like it keeps being connected and disconnected again and again. When I enable uvcvideo, I have some more error messages :

`[16096.480786] usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16096.480787] usb 1-13: Product: HD Webcam
[16096.480787] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[16096.480788] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[16096.483978] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device HD Webcam (04f2:b68b)
[16096.484051] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484129] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484208] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484288] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484367] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484448] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484528] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 7 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484608] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 8 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484688] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484768] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484848] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 1 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.484928] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.485007] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 5 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.485088] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[16096.485250] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[16096.485328] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -71 (exp. 48).
[16096.485329] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[16096.485663] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device HD Webcam (04f2:b68b)
[16096.485813] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[16096.485894] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -71 (exp. 48).
[16096.485895] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[16096.485965] usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 10`

Is there anything I can do or did my camera just suddenly died?